# Xero Api matching Accounts with Invoices

Tags: python, xero-api

I am trying to pull invoices by Accounts and have not managed to find a way to link the two. Am I missing something?

I tried through Contacts but it doesn't seem to have an Account or Account ID to match

I am using Pyxero for this, however this doesn't seem relevant, more so the data from xero api.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider providing source code in a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the actual error traceback. Read this [Howto](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It helps us to help you...

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - these details only appear when pulling an invoice one by one or paginated in the line items column.